# How to update account with asset value in batch class

Tags: apex, soql, batch, map, update

I have some assets related to accounts with a checkbox that need to update a checkbox on account. I tried to update the parent record but this gives me a nulpointer exception on line: ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c = ass.design_Solutions_Product__c;

How do I map the Ids of account in a bulkified way so I can update the checkbox with the related asset value.

My query is the following:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator (
            [SELECT account.Name, design_Solutions_Product__c, layertec_Product__c, simuleon_Product__c, account.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c,
             account.Actief_onderhoud_Layertec__c, account.Actief_onderhoud_Simuleon__c
             FROM Asset 
             WHERE (design_Solutions_Product__c = true AND account.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c = false) 
                    OR (layertec_Product__c = true AND account.Actief_onderhoud_Layertec__c  = false)
                    OR (simuleon_Product__c = true AND account.Actief_onderhoud_Simuleon__c = false)
             ]);        
    }
```

I tried to update the account with:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Asset> scope){        
        if(scope.size()!=Null){
            for (Asset ass : Scope) {
                if(ass.design_Solutions_Product__c !=null && ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c !=null) {
                    ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c = ass.design_Solutions_Product__c;
                }
                if(ass.layertec_Product__c !=null && ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Layertec__c !=null) {
                    ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Layertec__c = ass.layertec_Product__c;
                }
                if(ass.layertec_Product__c !=null && ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Simuleon__c !=null) {
                    ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Simuleon__c = ass.simuleon_Product__c;
                }
            }   
        }
    } update ass;
```

Comment: Which line is producing the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @DavidReed   ass.account.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c = ass.design_Solutions_Product__c;

Comment: It's technically possible for an `Asset` to not have `AccountId` populated. If you have any such Assets, that could be the cause.

Comment: @DavidReed  Could you place this as an answer as this was the solution for the nullpointer exception

Comment: Separate from the NPE...If you have a reference to a parent object (`Account`) in a child object (`Asset`), update a parent object field, and then call DML on the child object, are you sure that the parent object is actually updated? My intuition makes me think that the parent object would not be updated.

Comment: `if(scope.size()!=Null){` ... size will never return null. Further, scope is guaranteed to have at least one item in it. Also, you can't update the variable in the loop (DML in loop problem). Also, you meant to update the account record, not the asset record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible for the Asset's `AccountId` to be `null` in certain circumstances. Per the [Asset Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm):

> AccountId: (Required) ID of the Account associated with this asset. Must be a valid account ID. Required if ContactId is not specified.

This appears to be the only route whereby your code can produce a `NullPointerException.`

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a map that contains the accounts to update, and then update those values.

Your execute method should look like this:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Asset> scope){        
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
    Account tempRecord;
    for (Asset record: Scope) {
        if(record.AccountId == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if((tempRecord = accounts.get(record.AccountId)) == null) {
            tempRecord = new Account(Id=record.AccountId);
        }
        if(record.design_Solutions_Product__c !=null && record.account.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c !=null) {
            tempRecord.Actief_onderhoud_Design_Solutions__c = record.design_Solutions_Product__c;
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, tempRecord);
        }
        if(record.layertec_Product__c !=null && record.account.Actief_onderhoud_Layertec__c !=null) {
            tempRecord.Actief_onderhoud_Layertec__c = record.layertec_Product__c;
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, tempRecord);
        }
        if(record.simuleon_Product__c !=null && record.account.Actief_onderhoud_Simuleon__c !=null) {
            tempRecord.Actief_onderhoud_Simuleon__c = record.simuleon_Product__c;
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, tempRecord);
        }
    }
    update accounts.values();
}
```

Also, make sure you **add** AccountId to your initial query in order for this code to work.

I took the liberty of fixing a field reference, removing unnecessary logic, and generally cleaning up the code. Some additional work could be done (work I'd do if it were in my project, trading a bit of readability for a bit of performance), but should work just fine for your purposes.